# UITextField Aligment with leftview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, alignment

I have an UItextField, with an image on the leftView, but i need the UITextField to be Aligned to the center, and with the left view, it moves to the right.
Heres the code :

```
self.usernameField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
self.usernameField.placeholder = @"E-mail";
[self.usernameField setFont:[UIFont ralewayRegularFontWithSize:20]];
[self.usernameField setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
[self.usernameField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[self.usernameField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_placeholder"]];
[self.usernameField setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.usernameField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self.usernameField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[self.usernameField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[self.usernameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.usernameField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
self.usernameField.leftView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.usernameField.leftView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
[self.usernameField.leftView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
UIImageView *imgViewMail = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 25, 25)];
[imgViewMail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mail_icon"]];
[self.usernameField.leftView addSubview:imgViewMail];
[self.view addSubview:self.usernameField];
```

EDIT - Image Illustrating the problem. - The two First textFields
[image]

Comment: could you post any image to identify exact problem?

Comment: k in that you saying E-mail and senha should be centered right ?

Comment: It should be centered, more pixels to left.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom UITextField, and override these methods:

```
#pragma mark - Override UITextField

- (CGRect) textRectForBounds: (CGRect) bounds
{
  float x = bounds.origin.x + 50.f;
  float y = bounds.origin.y;
  float width  = bounds.size.width - (100.f);
  float height = bounds.size.height;

  return CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
}

- (CGRect) editingRectForBounds: (CGRect) bounds
{
  return [self textRectForBounds: bounds];
}
```

Comment: However, instead of `self.usernameField = [[UITextField alloc]...` it should be `self.usernameField = [[TextFieldCustom alloc]...` (name of your custom UITextField)